# Collect custom Doc annotations in Java/Kotlin project?

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations

I'm going to use lots of custom documentation notes all around code base of Kotlin and Java project. Seems like reasonable choice would be to use annotation.

As far as I know annotation is some sort of magic, handled by build tools. But I need to work with it in the Kotlin/Java code.

So we have two files `/src/some/thing.kt`

```
package some

annotation class Doc

@Doc
private fun some_doc() {
  println("some doc")
}
```

and `/src/generate_docs.kt`

```
fun main() {
  Find and call all the functions over all 
  the codebase marked with @Doc

  And then run some other code to process
  those notes and output HTML docs
}
```

How could it be done? Basically I can do it by manually writing all those calls, but I hope there's a better way.

```
fun main() {
  some_doc()
  another_doc()
  yet_another_doc()
  ...
  couple tens or hundreds more lines

  And then run some other code to process
  those notes and output HTML docs
}
```

If possible I would like to avoid Maven plugins and magic and just have plain old Java/Kotlin code I can run as `java GenerateDocsKt`.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do some classpath scanning. Are you already using any library to do it? [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph) looks interesting, it has links to other [alternatives](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph#alternatives) too.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón thanks, will check it out, no I'm not using any library, never processed annotations explicitly before.

Comment: Are you trying to do this at compile-time or at run-time? I assume the former. If this were Java then maybe you could make a custom [taglet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/jdk.javadoc/jdk/javadoc/doclet/Taglet.html). I'm not sure if Kotlin has anything similar.